# Sorting on non-additive ratios

Tags: number-theory, order-theory, ratio, additive-combinatorics

We are trying to aggregate and sort records by ratios (CTR = clicks/impressions). For some obscure reasons the technology we are using does not allow us to do this. We can group and sort on additive values (clicks or impressions) but we cannot calculate the CTR on the fly and sort on it.

I was hoping we can somehow move into the additive space by sorting aggregated additive values derived from clicks and impressions and in the end achieve the same order as if we would sort on CTR.

Example input data:

```
| ID | GroupId | clicks | views | order-value |
|----|---------|--------|-------|-------------|
| 1  | 1       | 5      | 10    |      x1     |
| 2  | 1       | 3      | 10    |      x2     |
| 3  | 1       | 1      | 10    |      x3     |
| 4  | 2       | 4      | 10    |      x4     |
| 5  | 2       | 6      | 10    |      x5     |
```

Grouped (summed) by `GroupID` and ordered by `ctr`:

```
| GroupId | clicks | views | ctr | agg-order-value |
|---------|--------|-------|-----|-----------------|
| 2       | 10     | 20    | 0.5 |   sum(x4, x5)   |
| 1       | 9      | 30    | 0.3 | sum(x1, x2, x3) |
```

Is there any other way to get the same aggregated order but without actually needing to calculate the CTR ratio?

Perhaps we can introduce new additive `order-values` (`x1-x5`) to the input data table (derived from clicks and impressions) that could help us achieve the same sorting? It would have to have a property that the sum of those order-values would need to preserve the same order as the calculated `ctr`.

I am hoping we can solve our technology limitation by some clever math idea, not really sure if it's possible.

Comment: You could sort on log(clicks) - log(views), but will your technology count that as a "non-additive" value?  What exactly are the limitations?

Comment: This is a brilliant idea! We can store `log(clicks)-log(views)` on each record and aggregate and sort on it. Is it a common technique? How would you best describe how does it work? I would be very happy to accept that this an answer. Limitation details are a bit technical, I tried to describe here the essence. For a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359879/sort-term-aggregation-by-script

Comment: @MichaelLugo Would ordering on sum of log(clicks) - log(views) across various aggregates keep the same ordering as sum(clicks)/sum(views)? From my initial tests it looks that unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Adding x1-x5 values so their aggregated ordering would correspond to the final CTR ratios is probably not such a simple problem. My idea so far was to perhaps model the ratios with beta distributions and somehow add them but it looks rather complex.

Comment: The problem is that if you just have two groups of sizes $a,b$ with the same data within each group,  then the sizes $a,b$ do not matter for the CTR ordering but matter a lot for any "additive ordering" of the groups if you allow the order value to depend only on the data for this particular order, so the short answer is "No". Still, you can do something that is not as good as you want but, possibly, useful: to put all groups for which $CTR\ge z$ before all groups with $CTR<z$ with any fixed $z$. All you need for that is to define the order value as $clicks-z\times views$.

Comment: @fedja Thanks, this is very interesting. Do you think it would be possible if we use different aggregation function instead of the `sum`? We can use `avg`, `percentile` or even implement our own custom simple aggregations. In any case, I would be happy to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Datageek Depends on what you mean by "simple aggregation". If you can formalize this notion, then I (or somebody else) can think about it. To start with, is it necessary that your "simple aggregation" acts on a single column? (if not, log(sum(clicks))-log(sum(views)) would certainly do the job, but is it allowed?)

Comment: @fedja I will study the limitations and will get back here with a more formal description, and another bounty.